# Why can't it find the column from the active range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Fairly new and trying to set up an alert dialog but I can't figure out why my "var column" isn't working when i test the code. The dialog window should alert whoever clicks the button that they're about to copy *customer name* to *current month's* tab in the Job Book.

Where am I going wrong?

```
function onOpen() {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
          .createMenu('Custom Menu')
          .addItem('Show alert', 'showAlert')
          .addToUi();
    }

function showAlert() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = ss.getActiveRange();
  var column = range.getRange(range.getRowIndex(), 1).getValue();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var getMonth = Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMM");

  var copyTest = ui.alert(
     'This will copy customer '&column&' to the '&getMonth&' JOB BOOK tab.',
     'Do you want to continue?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {

    ui.alert('Customer '&column&' has been copied to the JOB BOOK.');
  } else {

    ui.alert('Operation cancelled. You"'"ll get em next time, tiger.');
  }
```

}

Comment: Can you provide the detail information about `my "var column" isn't working`? If an error occurs, can you show it? And in your script, I think that when the script is saved, an error occurs at `ui.alert('Operation cancelled. You"'"ll get em next time, tiger.');`. How about this?

Answer (score 1):

```
var column = range.getRange(range.getRowIndex(), 1).getValue();
```

Should read:

```
var column = ss.getRange(range.getRowIndex(), 1).getValue();
```